# Checkboxes in the rows of lightning-datatable frozen

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a simple lightning-datatable in a lwc component. Here am trying to select and deselect the checkboxes for the first two row, which unfortunately seems frozen and doesn't allow me check. Strangely it automatically checks the checkbox in the third row -

[image]

Here's my HTML template -

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Scheduled Classes" icon-name="standard:schedule_objective">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-spread">
            <lightning-datatable data={scheduledClassesData} columns={columns} key-field="Id">
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

And this is my JS -

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import fetchSchedulerClasses from '@salesforce/apex/SchedulerBatchUtils.retrieveScheduledClasses';


export default class SchedulerClassCmp extends LightningElement {
    scheduledClassesData;
    columns = [];

    connectedCallback(){
        this.columns = [
            {label: 'Id', fieldName: 'Id'},
            {label: 'Class Name', fieldName: 'ClassName'}
        ]
    }

    @wire(fetchSchedulerClasses)
    wiredFetchScheduledClasses({error,data}){
        if (data) {
            this.scheduledClassesData = data;
        } else if (error) {
            // Handle error 
        }
    }
}
```

Apex Class -

```
public class SchedulerBatchUtils {
    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<ApexTypeImplementor> retrieveScheduledClasses(){
        return [SELECT Id, ClassName, ApexClassId FROM ApexTypeImplementor WHERE InterfaceName = 'Schedulable'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your apex class as well? and did you try clearing your cache and reload the browser?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @prem22
Have included Apex Class as well. And yes, I cleared my cache, tried in incognito, used a different browser, but no avail

Comment: Can you change the `key-field="Id"` to `key-field="ClassName"` in the datatable and try?

Comment: @Sam Great thanks! I replaced it with ClassName/ApexClassId and it works with both